# TFS Build based on path

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I'm trying to automate a build schema that would mainly follow the promotion of a specific build through environment, through branches.

So, my source code looks like this:

- DEV branch
- QA branch (child from DEV)
- PROD branch (child from QA)

Now, I have already set up continuous builds in the DEV branch. Basically, for every checkin a build is scheduled and unit tests are executed.

I want to be able to merge any set of checkins from DEV to QA and make that automatically trigger the QA build. However, I can't find any option that would build based on files changed on a specific path. **Is this possible? How to achieve it?**

PS: I know I could as well trigger this build for every checkin, but I would find more value to do so only when a specific path is changed, so that the build can be associated with a set of checkins to automatically generate a change-log of the "release". Also, the same idea would apply into PROD releases, which may be a set of multiple QA releases.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the default behavior (any checkin beneath your workspace mapping causes a build) not appropriate here?  Are there *other* checkins going into your QA branch?  Is your build workspace mapping for QA required to be of a larger scope than the paths you want to build after a checkin?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I think my problem was that I just didn't know that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Workspace Mapping in the build definition also determines which path's trigger a CI build.  So just make sure your workspace mapping is specified for hte DEV/QA/PROD path's appropriately, and it will only trigger builds for that check-ins within that branch.